# Cassandra key definitions

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and this may have been covered somewhere, but, I haven't been able to find it here, on Planet Cassandra, or, in the DataStax documentation.

I have inherited a set of keyspaces created by another programmer who has left the company. There is a particular data item that he was supposed to have stored in the keyspace, however, it's not listed in the schema (displayed from the Cassandra CLI). 
The programmer stated that it was in the 'blob', however, there aren't any columns in the keyspace defined as a 'blob'.

When I use the DataStax DevCenter tool, however, there is a 'key' column listed as a 'blob' that isn't in the schema...

key (blob)
assignExpirydate (text)
bookingClass (text)
... etc.

Since it wasn't in the schema, I'm assuming that the column is created by Cassandra, and, not what I'm looking for, but, I would like to verify that.

So, my question is, is there some documentation that refers to (or person that knows) whether Cassandra creates this column? A quick explanation of it would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the table was created using an older version of cassandra through the cassandra-cli, you may not see it in dev center.  You should take a look at the docs on using "thrift" tables from "cql3" to see what is going on.  If you use the cassandra-cli and do a list on the table it should show you all the data in there.  When using thrift you can insert data with any column name you want, it doesn't have to be defined in the schema.

Links to thrift/cql3 information:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows